# copy column from one table to another mysql with multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have write this query

```
INSERT INTO  table1 set Name=(SELECT Name FROM  table2)
```

it gives **#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row** error,

please help me with the correct query.

thanks,
krishna

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax for **[`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)** is wrong. Try

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (Name)
SELECT Name FROM table2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac94/1)** demo.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be doing `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Name)
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM table2
```